# Printing a YouTube video feed in php

Tags: php, youtube, wordpress, youtube-api

I'm in the beginning stages of writing a plugin to display YouTube videos in a WordPress implementation. Here is my code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Youtube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

function getAndPrintVideoFeed($location::'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thelanzolini/uploads/-/step') {
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
  // set the version to 2 to receive a version 2 feed of entries
  $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
  $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($location);
  printVideoFeed($videoFeed);
}

function printVideoFeed($videoFeed) {
  $count = 1;
  foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry) {
    echo "Entry # " . $count . "\n";
    printVideoEntry($videoEntry);
    echo "\n";
    $count++;
  }
}
```

All I get is this error:

[image]

I am using MAMP. php is version 5.4.10.

**Switching the `$location::` above for a `$location =` I get no errors within the actual plugin file itself but rather in loading various components of Zend.**

### Errors:

> Warning: include_once(Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /Users/mrcsmcln/Documents/MAMP/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/youtube-filter/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 134
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Youtube.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in
>   /Users/mrcsmcln/Documents/MAMP/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/youtube-filter/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 134
>
> Warning: require_once(Zend/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /Users/mrcsmcln/Documents/MAMP/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/youtube-filter/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 86
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Zend/Exception.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in
>   /Users/mrcsmcln/Documents/MAMP/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/youtube-filter/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 86

What is wrong with my code? Is there a better way I can go about all this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAndPrintVideoFeed($location::'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thelanzolini/uploads/-/step') {
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
  // set the version to 2 to receive a version 2 feed of entries
  $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
  $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($location);
  printVideoFeed($videoFeed);
}
```

Should? possibly? be this: Not familiar with ZF buth this is the regular syntax atleast.

```
function getAndPrintVideoFeed($location = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thelanzolini/uploads/-/step') {
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
  // set the version to 2 to receive a version 2 feed of entries
  $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
  $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($location);
  printVideoFeed($videoFeed);
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Even more errors, but they're all in the Zend files, so there's something.

Comment: You should verify the path for your includes are correct. Where is your class located in relation to the Loader.php?